# How to allow users to edit protected range through script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet with a protected range which permissions are set to only allow me to edit it. I have a function in the sheet's script which edits cells in the protected range. I rigged up the function to fire on edit which allows users other than myself to run the function successfully since it runs using my permissions.

So that scenario is all fine and dandy, however I complicate things by wanting to display a loading message while the function is running. To do this I created the html file below:

```
<script>
  function onSuccess() {
    google.script.host.close();
  }

  function onFailure() {
    var div = document.getElementById('result');
    div.innerHTML = '<div>Data failed to load.</div>';
  }

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).withFailureHandler(onFailure).process();
</script>

<div id='result'><img src="https://c4a54d10381f750e81dcc323aed21e2c95725815.googledrive.com/host/0Bwyqwd2fAHMMallsNkNOV0RfcTg/wait_progress.gif"></div>
```

The html is displayed when the following function is triggered by the on edit event:

```
function refresh() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('loading').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).setWidth(100).setHeight(100);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Processing...');
}
```

The user receives an error saying that he/she cannot edit a protected cell. I assume this happens because the refresh() function runs with my permissions but the process() function runs with his/her permissions. Any ideas on how I can make this work for me?

Edit - 
I tried to use the following code to solve my problem:

```
function refresh() {
  setPermission(1);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('loading').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).setWidth(100).setHeight(100);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Processing...');

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  setPermission(0);
}

function setPermission(flag)
{
  var me = Session.getActiveUser();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  var protection = protections[0];

  if (flag == 1)
  {
    protection.addEditor(me);
  } else {
    protection.removeEditor(me);
  }
}
```

It starts to work because the process() function does change some cells in the protected range but then the same error saying the user cannot edit the protected range shows up. I believe it's because showModalDialog doesn't suspend the script so before process() can finish the user's permission to edit the protected range is taken away.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to do this.
1) if you know how to do the oauth calls manually (an oauth2 apps script library is out there to help) you could have your account refresh token saved and use it to make the sheet api calls in your name (through urlFetch). 
2) publish another script that runs in your name with anonymous which does the changes by receiving url parameters. Call that script from your original script with urlFetch. this is easier to code that (1) but might me slower.
you might also need to use a custom installed  onEditTrigger if you have permission issues with urlFetch or other apis.

Comment: I tried to act using your suggestions and I seem to be stuck and need some help.  I created a separate script file which contains the process() function and call it from the doGet() function.  I published this script as a web app which I set to run as me and when I access the url from my web browser the results of the process() function are realized.  I then go to my original script and have a function which calls UrlFetchApp.fetch(<my web app url>) and I don't see the expected results.

Comment: Make sure the 2nd script is published as anonymous access.

Comment: I'm operating within a domain so my only options are myself or anyone in the domain.  I chose anyone in domain.

Comment: Aha. Your admin has explicitly disabled the option to share anonymously from admin.google.com. If they cant revert it, your only option is my (1) which potentially exposes your token to editors.

Comment: If you could at least share to your external gmail you could publish the 2nd script there.

Comment: Could I just modify my current UrlFetchApp call to include the oauth param?

Comment: hi, I'm facing same problem, can unprotect-then-protect cell do this?

Comment: I do this and get an HTML page. I visit the site and see the json output, but the get request from my script gives me the html webpage with my code in an iframe. Do you know why this is?

Comment: NVM, figured it out, need to do ContentService.createTextOutput and not html output like the example shows. BTW, it would be helpful if you could link to exactly the places one needs to follow to set this up. It would save anyone else some time as they search for all the pieces to do these two options.